# libcurl-x64.dll was not found

Tags: c++, json, windows, dll, g++

I'm reciving a very odd error. I'm compiling a code which parses JSON data from a url using libcurl. After trial and error I've gotten it compiled without error. However, when trying to run the code I get a *system* error, saying  libcurl-x64.dll was not found. 
[Picture of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSwLC.png)
I'm not exactly sure what is finding what, here. My windows system cannot find  libcurl-x64.dll or is it my gcc compiler? Nevertheless, a quick system search shows the location of it. I didn't use it for anything. What exactly do I need to do with  libcurl-x64.dll so that my system can find it? It only pertains to this one parsing program I'm doing, every other cpp/exe file and project works fine. System specs: Windows 10, Dev C++ IDE, mingw g++ compiler. 
Here is the location of my supposedly missing file:
[FilePath1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro2Vj.png)
[FilePath2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TCVe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [search order of DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) for desktop Windows applications is as follows:

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The system directory. (e.g. \Windows\System32 or \Windows\SysWOW64)
3. The Windows directory. (e.g. \Windows)
4. The current directory.
5. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

You need to make sure the missing DLL is reachable via one of the above locations.

The best for a quick test is to copy it to the same location where your application (.exe) is located.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with your compiler. On any OS that supports dynamic
libaries (DLLs on Windows, shared libraries on Linux, etc.), if a program has
been linked to some dynamic library at linktime then, at runtime, the OS
program loader must be able to find that dynamic library in
one of the places where it looks for dynamic libraries by default, or in one
of the places that you specify at runtime in some OS-dependent manner.

This is the nature of dynamic libraries.

In the case of Windows, it means that to run a program you have linked with
`libcurl-x64.dll` the program loader will try to locate `libcurl-x64.dll`
using the [Search Path Used by Windows to Locate a DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx),
in order to load it into your program's process. If it fails to find `libcurl-x64.dll` in any of those places
then the program will fail to start, with the error you observed.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded those files, put them in the project folder and the program ran.